# How to test a value under a condition during 1 minutes in java

Tags: java, swing

Could you please tell me how I can test if a value is below some threshold during 1 minute in java ?

e.g value = 50. if value<20 more than 1 minutes do ....

Thanks.

Abs

Comment: Consider re-asking this question, but when you do, you'll want to give enough information so that it is actually answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this question swing therefore I suppose that this value is set in a `JComponent` such as  a `JTextField`.

In such a case, the easiest approach would be attaching the appropriate listener (let's call it 'L') to that `JComponent`. For a JTextField, you could use a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)

When your component's value is updated, 'L' will be invoked and:
- if the new value is < 20, you trigger a one minute [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that will execute your action. Let's call that timer 'T'
- otherwise, if 'T' was running, you cancel it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's working now I used a timer and I set the setinitaliedelay to 1 min and recheck the value if < 20 then trigger alarm. Yes this value is shown in Jtextfiel I'm  monitoring the router interfaces and would trigger an alarm if the threshold is exceeded.